# Hacer que un pushButton cierre un Qdialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Al hacer click en el `QPushButton` da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "listageneral.py", line 59, in adios
>     self.close()
> AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'close'
> ```

Este es el código:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import sqlite3
form_class = uic.loadUiType("listageneral.ui")[0]
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def iniciarbase(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('condo3.db') as con:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM aptos")
            self.lista.setRowCount(0)
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(cursor):
                self.lista.insertRow(row_number)
                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.lista.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    self.lista.resizeColumnToContents(column_number)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(750, 580)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 540, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lista = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 700, 461))
        self.lista.setRowCount(111)
        self.lista.setColumnCount(4)
        self.lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lista"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 301, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.adios)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.iniciarbase()

    def adios(self):
        self.close()
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cerrar", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Listado General de Propietarios</span></p></body></html>", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edición:**

Al intentar aplicar `Dialog.close()` en el QMainWindow obtengo el siguiente error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Python\PyQt\Condominio\listagenera‌​l.py", line 59, in adios
         Dialog.close()
  NameError: name 'Dialog' is not defined
```

Este es el código:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from listageneral import *
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def dialogo(self, checked=None):
        if checked==None: return
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(714, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 661, 401))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.listgen = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.listgen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 75, 23))
        self.listgen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listgen"))
        self.listgen.clicked.connect(self.dialogo)      
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.listgen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista General", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Consulta", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu clase `UI_Dialog` no es un `QtDialog` ni hereda de el y tampoco tiene implementado el método `close`. Si lo que quieres es cerrar tu instancia `Dialog` debes usar su método:

```
def adios(self):
    Dialog.close()
```

**Edición:**

Deberias hacer que todo lo concerniente a tu `QtDialog` esté en tu clase `UI_Dialog`, no en tu ventana principal. No obstante, sin modificar mucho tu idea deberías parsarle el objeto `QtDialog` a tu clase `UI_Dialog` al instanciarla:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from listageneral import *


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def dialogo(self, checked=None):
        if checked==None: return
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog(dialog)
        dialog.ui.setupUi()
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(714, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 661, 401))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.listgen = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.listgen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 75, 23))
        self.listgen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listgen"))
        self.listgen.clicked.connect(self.dialogo)      
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.listgen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista General", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Consulta", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tu clase `UI_Dialog` debe ser:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def __init__(self,  dialog):
        self.dialog = dialog

    def iniciarbase(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('condo3.db') as con:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM aptos")
            self.lista.setRowCount(0)
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(cursor):
                self.lista.insertRow(row_number)
                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.lista.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    self.lista.resizeColumnToContents(column_number)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        self.dialog.resize(750, 580)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 540, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lista = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.dialog)
        self.lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 700, 461))
        self.lista.setRowCount(111)
        self.lista.setColumnCount(4)
        self.lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lista"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 301, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.adios)
        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.dialog)
        self.iniciarbase()

    def adios(self):
        self.dialog.close()
    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cerrar", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Listado General de Propietarios</span></p></body></html>", None))
```

Como digo generalmente es encapsular adecuadamente el codigo, "dejar que el `QDialog` se encargue de los suyo y la clase de la ventana principal de lo suyo". Otra posible implementación seria:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from listageneral import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        self.resize(714, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 661, 401))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.listgen = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.listgen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 75, 23))
        self.listgen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listgen"))
        self.listgen.clicked.connect(self.dialogo)      
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.show()

        self.retranslateUi()
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def dialogo(self, checked=None):
        if checked==None: return
        Ui_Dialog()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.listgen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista General", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Consulta", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tu clase `Ui_Dialog` seria algo así:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def iniciarbase(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('condo3.db') as con:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM aptos")
            self.lista.setRowCount(0)
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(cursor):
                self.lista.insertRow(row_number)
                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.lista.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    self.lista.resizeColumnToContents(column_number)

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.resize(750, 580)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 540, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lista = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.lista.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 700, 461))
        self.lista.setRowCount(111)
        self.lista.setColumnCount(4)
        self.lista.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lista"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 301, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.adios)
        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.iniciarbase()
        self.exec_()

    def adios(self):
        self.close()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cerrar", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Listado General de Propietarios</span></p></body></html>", None))
```

Comment: Sirvio la solucion para el QDialog, pero al llamarlo de la MainWinow, al hacer click en el boton cerrar me da este error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Python\PyQt\Condominio\listageneral.py", line 59, in adios
    Dialog.close()
NameError: name 'Dialog' is not defined

Comment: @MarcoSalazar haria falta ver el código para ver como llamas tu `Ui_dialog` desde el tu `QMainWindow`, tienes que llamar el método `close` de tu objeto QtGui.QDialog()  de cualquier forma. Te aconsejo que te mires e intentes comprender primero el concepto de programación orientada a objetos y su implementación en Python, Posiblemente seria mas simple si tu clase `UI_dialog` heredara de `QtDialog` directamente.

Comment: he editado la pregunta y colocado el codigo de la MainWindow

Comment: @MarcoSalazar he editado la pregunta mira a ver que tal. Supongo que tu clase `UI_Dialog` esta dentro del modulo `listageneral`. Por cierto, la forma de importar `from listageneral import *` es por norma general una mala practica. Entre otras causas está que dificulta la legibilidad del código, por ejemplo no se sabe de forma explicita de donde viene `UI_dialog`.

Comment: funciona pero al salir da el siguiente error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listageneral2.py", line 69, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
TypeError: setupUi() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @MarcoSalazar si te refieres al penúltimo ejemplo que te doy  debe ser `ui = Ui_Dialog(Dialog)` y `ui.setupUi()`. El objeto `QtDialog` se le pasa solo a la instancia de `Ui_Dialog` no a sus métodos.

Comment: Excelente ahora si. Nada facil esto de python, pero voy a seguir intentando. gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia.